# How to modify the style of asp.net page that use asp:Content to css-page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a problem i want to change the background-color but the css file dose not let me so i have to put it in a style tag in asp page

```
<asp:Content Id="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"  Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css"> body{background-color:#e4dfdf;}</style>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: In what way does this not work?  Is it not rendering to the output?  When you debug in the browser, is this style being applied at all?  Also, why does the CSS file "not let you"?

Comment: I want to change my background as u can see in the code above. But I have to put it in a style-tag in my asp.net page(html) for it to work. When i put the same code "background-color: #e4dfdf;" the background color does not show. The CSS is rightly refered to. Everything else seems to work.

Comment: As you talk about CSS I'm assuming that you display this page in a browser. What would be interesting in that case is the HTML Code your ASP produces, not the ASP itself. COuld you add this to your post as well as the *relevant* CSS

Comment: i want to do this in my css #Content2{ Background-color:#e4dfdf; } instead of writing it in my ASP-page

Answer (score 0):

In your master page, you have to include a ContentPlaceHolder element, and in your page add a Content element and give it the ContentPlaceHolderID you gave to the Master page head:

In the Master page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In your page:

```
<asp:Content Id="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css"> body{background-color:#e4dfdf;}</style>
</asp:Content>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I already tried this. It works. But THE ANSWER I want is to add the style in my CSS-file. Because I wanna use this code in multiple pages without adding it to every single page.

Comment: I think since you're using a master page, the ID of your content element is different on the rendered page than the aspx .. you have to check the client id of your element i.e "Content2".

Comment: Ok.. i change my mind im writing this code in my master pager and it dosent work ' <asp:ContentPlaceHolder  Id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">  
                       <style type="text/css"> body{background-color:#e4dfdf;}</style>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>'

Comment: No my friend you have to add the style tag in the Content tag in your page not the master page (not in the ContentPlaceHolder of the master page).